# What is the usage of the client_secrets.json file?

Tags: google-api

I am working on writing a program using the Google Tasks API in Python.  I have downloaded and run the sample application from Google, and it comes with a file called `client_secrets.json`.  I understand that the file is used for OAuth authentication, but my question is should I distribute this file to users?  Should I push it to my public source repo?  Or is it supposed to be kept secret?  If I shouldn't share it, how would other users do the authentication?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: While the answer from @user3490818 is valid, I wonder if that is always true. What if APIs enabled on that `client_secrets.json` have no access to any resources where quota is being consumed? What if you are writing an application which is only accessing user's google drive - should the user be enabling developer API for that purpose alone? I don't think it's reasonable. What if you register an account solely for the purpose of creating redistributable `client_secrets.json`? If you figure anything out, can you please post update here

Comment: any ideas where I should download `client_secrets.json`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Google API Client Library OAuth2 docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/guide/aaa_oauth) states,

> Keep your client secret private. If someone obtains your client
>   secret, they could use it to consume your quota, incur charges against
>   your Developers Console project, and request access to user data.

So don't commit or otherwise distribute the file.

If you want to publicly share your application source code, instruct others to use their own Google Developer account to register their own Google Developer project and generate their own app OAuth credentials (client_secrets.json file) for use with their "installation" of the app.

If you were making the application commercially available, you would seemingly need to share the app credentials with them in a trusted, legally protected, or secure manner.

Answer (score 10):

Apparently the client_secrets.json file does not have to be kept secret for installed application. From https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2?csw=1#CS in the "Installed applications" section:

> The process results in a client ID and, in some cases, a client secret, which you embed in the source code of your application. (In this context, the client secret is obviously not treated as a secret.)

So if you're making a webapp, keep it secret. If it's a python app that you distribute to users and they run on their own, it does not have to be kept secret.

Comment: Im guessing a git-hub hosted open source python app would have to keep its `client_secrets.json` file hidden somehow?

Comment: The documentation isn't clear why it's OK to not keep the client_secret a secret. Why do the risks in the other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25597526/803801) not apply? Also, these docs by Google have conflicting messages: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/installed-app. It says that "The client ID and client secret obtained from the API Console are embedded in the source code of your application. In this context, the client secret is obviously not treated as a secret." but also says "Do not store the client_secrets.json file in a publicly-accessible location"

Comment: @gsingh2011 There are no conflicts. If you are creating an app that will only run in a trusted environment (e.g., a web server) then you should keep client_secret a secret. But in the case of 'installed applications' which will run in an untrusted environment, you cannot keep any secret. That is why Google says "it is not treated as a secret".