# Can Google API client secret file be transferred?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api

I downoaded the client secret file succesfully and it works.
Can I email my client_secret json file to someone. 
Basically I want to use it on another pc. Should I download a new one? Is there a problem if i transfer it? Can someone explain how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/guide/aaa_oauth), keep your client secret private. If someone obtains your client secret, they could use it to consume your quota, incur charges against your Developers Console project, and request access to user data. It is also stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25597526/5832311) that if you want to publicly share your application source code, instruct others to use their own Google Developer account to register their own Google Developer project and generate their own app OAuth credentials (client_secrets.json file) for use with their "installation" of the app.