# Should I keep my client_secret.json hidden from user?

Tags: google-oauth

I have created a desktop .NET C# application, which utilizes Google API (particularly Google Drive) through official .NET library and OAuth 2.0.

According to the official example, I use `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker` with `client_secret.json` file, downloaded from the Google Developer Console for my project. It is stated in the docs that I should keep my developer's secret private (which seems logical to me), but in the following examples, it is saved to a plain file, which is copied to application build directory during build. So application user is able to open my file and grab my secret.

**Question**: should I place `client_secret.json` content in a protected place (like maybe just hardcode its values in the most naive case), or am I missing something and a plain file is not insecure in this case?

Comment: Take a look to this post, you can find your answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761126/what-is-the-usage-of-the-client-secrets-json-file

Comment: @Ali.Ghodrat, thanks, I've already seen this question. However, it has two contradictory answers: one stating that "share the app credentials with them in a trusted, legally protected, or secure manner.", and another that "app that you distribute to users and they run on their own, it does not have to be kept secret.". I am not able to decide which one is right.